# Confused on identity and is operator

Tags: python, python-2.6

I recently saw this code:

```
x = [2, 3, 4]
if type(x) is list:
    #some logic
```

and was confused how the `if` condition went off...I thought that `is` checks for memory identity and the `id` of `x` is different from the `id` of `list`, but if that's the case how did this `if` condition even go off? (I was under the impression that the only native singleton in Python was `None`).

Comment: It's not checking the id of x. It's checking the id of the type of x.

Comment: @M4rtini I still get different `id` values from `id(type(x))` and `id(type(list))`

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian `type(list)` is `type`, and `type(x)` is `list`, why will there IDs be same?

Comment: `id(type(x))` and `id(list)` should give you the same id. `type(list)` simply give you the type of the type object, and will not be the same.

Comment: How many copies of the `list` type do you think there are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `x` is an instance of class `list`, in new style classes `type()` returns the class of the instance itself, i.e `list` in this case. Consider this simple example:

```
>>> class A(object):
    pass
... 
>>> type(A())         #calling type on the instance returns its class
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> type(A()) is A
True
```

Note that the above example will not work for user defined old-style classes as all the instances there were of type `instance`.

```
>>> class A:
    pass
... 
>>> type(A())
<type 'instance'>
```